# How can I supress a property or method from a base-class in a derived class in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

Supose a base class

```
Public Class airplane

Private var_num_seats As Integer
Private var_num_engines As Integer

Protected Property num_seats As Integer
    Get
        Return var_num_seats
    End Get
    Set(ByVal param_num_seats As Integer)
        var_num_seats = param_num_seats
    End Set
End Property

Protected Friend Property num_engines As Integer
    Get
        Return var_num_engines

    End Get
    Set(ByVal param_num_engines As Integer)
        var_num_engines = param_num_engines
    End Set
End Property

Protected Friend Sub take_off()
    'Do take off tasks
End Sub

Protected Friend Sub start_engines()
    'start each engine
End Sub

End Class
```

And a child class

```
Public Class glider
Inherits airplane

Private var_towed As Boolean
Private var_glide_rate As Double

Public ReadOnly Property towed As Boolean
    Get
        Return var_towed
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property glide_rate As Double
    Get
        Return var_glide_rate
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub to_glide()
    'do gliding
End Sub

End Class
```

Obviously, I don't wish that the class Glider has the method "start_engines" neither the property "num_engines". Otherwise, other child classes may have. How can I supress these property and method in child class, not just ignoring (if I can)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You Cant!**

Reason:  Breaks object orientedness!!!!

Suppose you have:

```
public void ThisIsAMethod(Airplane plane)
{
    plane.start_engines();
}
```

Now you use it as such:

```
Airplane aPlane = new Glider();
ThisIsAMethod(aPlane);
```

Oh no, aPlane is really a glider, and hence you shouldn't be able to call it.  However, it is an airplane and thus has the method.

Solution:

1. Form a true inheritence.  A glider is not an airplane.  Maybe you can have a base class for "FlyingMachine" or "WingedFlier" or something which they both extend.
2. Hackmode!  In Glider:

   Protected Friend Sub start_engines()
       throw new NotSupportedException()
   End Sub

Comment: Multiple exclamation marks are a sure sign of a diseased mind.

Comment: I just got really excited while answering ;)

Comment: +0.49.  Any airplane should be able to `start_engines()` without worrying about the operation not being supported, as it's part of the interface. (Note, though, that `start_engines()` doesn't necessarily have to *do* anything, aside from presumably making the plane ready to move. A glider having no engines to start, it could just return.) Likewise, `num_engines` could always return 0. (It should really be read-only or 'private set' anyway!  Planes shouldn't be able to change their engine count.)  But yes, if a glider is used differently from an airplane, one should not inherit from the other.

Comment: Yes, I think that there is a question about conceptual designing of the classes. I just wondering if it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking to use an interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9xt0sdd.aspx

Comment: Interesting... In the interface I shouldn't declare start_engines and num_engines and, this way, avoid the operation?

Comment: It's been a while since I had my head in any of my VB code, will have to get back to you on that.